# Adding a column to csv based on other rows with d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm using D3 and JavaScript to manipulate some csv data. The idea is that it documents where people go throughout the day: they might start at home, go to the grocery store, school, work, etc. Each time someone moves from where they are, a new row in the csv file is logged. So, when Sally wakes up, it logs `Sally,home`, when she leaves for school, it logs `Sally,school`, etc. The places are arbitrary, and can go in any order, and there may be more places.

My csv file looks like this:

```
name,place
Sally,home
Joe,home
Bill,work
Joe,work
Sally,school
Sally,grocery
Bill,salon
Joe,grocery
```

I want to add a column to each row with the next step of the same person. Essentially, I want the data to reflect the transition between `home` and `school`, between `school` and `grocery`, or whatever the adjacent steps are. In the first data point, Sally is at home, and the next time she is mentioned, she is at school. So I want the first data point, instead of being simply `Sally, home`, to change to `Sally, home, school` to reflect the transition. So, the above, after manipulation, should look like this:

```
name,place,next
Sally,home,school
Joe,home,work
Bill,work,salon
Joe,work,grocery
Sally,school,grocery
Sally,grocery
Bill,salon
Joe,grocery
```

Then, I want to delete the last step for each person: basically, anything that doesn't have a "next" column (these might not always be the last three rows). The end result looks like this:

```
name,place,next
Sally,home,school
Joe,home,work
Bill,work,salon
Joe,work,grocery
Sally,school,grocery
```

My only idea for this is to use nested for loops to find the next matching name, and then somehow add the new column... this is my attempt, but you can't just declare a new column like that.

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    for(j=0; j<data.length; j++){
        if (data[i].name === data[j].name){
            data[i].next = data[j].place;
            break;
        }
    }
}
});
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated (the end goal is to be able to put this flow into D3's Sankey diagram, if that helps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by *"but you can't just declare a new column like that"*? Yes, you can (of course, I'm taking about the data array, which is what you're going to use, not the actual CSV. However, if you actually want to **save** a new CSV file, please edit your question accordingly and remove the D3 tag, since D3 has no method for this).

The only change I'm gonna do in your code is starting the inner (`j`) loop one position after the outer (`i`) loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (data[i].name === data[j].name) {
      data[i].next = data[j].place;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, we remove the objects without a `next` property:

```
var finalData = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.next
});
```

Here is the demo with your data:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (data[i].name === data[j].name) {
      data[i].next = data[j].place;
      break;
    }
  }
}
var finalData = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.next
});

console.log(finalData)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">name,place
Sally,home
Joe,home
Bill,work
Joe,work
Sally,school
Sally,grocery
Bill,salon
Joe,grocery</pre>
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed this; I was getting an `Invalid left-hand side in assignment` error, and I thought it was because of the `data[i].next` line... turns out I wasn't paying attention and it was erroring when I tried to print it, because instead of concatenating the string with a plus sign I mistyped as an equals sign. Thanks for the loop starting place correction and the time you had to spend on my carelessness!

Answer (score -1):

Yes I know, this is C# not Javascript like the tag on your question. Though I am most proficient in C#, I'm in a hurry, and I want to help... So here's a concept you could respin in Javascript.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ManipulatingCSV_45044259
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            /*here I'm just making a list of string that basically represents each line of your file*/
            List<string> textlines = new List<string>();
            textlines.Add("name,place");
            textlines.Add("Sally, home");
            textlines.Add("Joe,home");
            textlines.Add("Bill, work");
            textlines.Add("Joe,work");
            textlines.Add("Sally, school");
            textlines.Add("Sally,grocery");
            textlines.Add("Bill, salon");
            textlines.Add("Joe,grocery");

            Dictionary<string, string> cummulatedValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //iterates through the lines of text
            foreach (string item in textlines)
            {
                string[] splitted = item.Split(',');//split using the delimiter

                if (cummulatedValues.Keys.Contains(splitted[0]))
                {
                    //we already have this person, lets add something to the entry
                    cummulatedValues[splitted[0]] += "," + splitted[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    //this is a new person, lets create an entry
                    cummulatedValues.Add(splitted[0], splitted[1]);
                }
            }

            //Now we'll write the new file.
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("pathtofile.txt"))
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in cummulatedValues)
                {
                    /*Since you want only people who have been to more than 1 place*/
                    if (item.Value.Split(',').Length > 1)
                    {
                        //if there are more than 1 place listed
                        sw.WriteLine(item.Key + "," + item.Value);//write the line
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```